# How To Develop The post method web api in ASP.NEY c# with json data with array

Tags: asp.net-web-api

Please help the below format to develop post meth web api to store the data into Database.
{
"jobcardID": "100023",
"breakdownID": "417217",
"vehicleNumber": "UP32GB4717",
"ODOmeter": 3023232,
" spareparts ":
[
{
"spItemCode": 231,
"spitemName": "Engine Oil",
"spitemCost": "234",
"spitemManhours": "2",
"spitemEstStartDTM ": "2021-06-04 12:32:59",
"spitemEstEndDTM": "2021-06-04 12:35:59"
},
{
"spItemCode": 342,
"spitemName": "Piston",
"spitemCost": "3450",
"spitemManhours": "5",
"spitemEstStartDTM ": "2021-06-04 12:32:59",
"spitemEstEndDTM": "2021-06-04 12:35:59"
}
]
" totalSpareCost":8000,
“totalLabourTime":”23hrs”,
“totalLabourCost":2000,
“TotalCost":10000,
“vehicleRecoveryTime":"2021-06-04 12:35:59",
}

Comment: please tell me about your database structure and tables

Comment: database -sql. table : jobcardID
    breakdownID
    vehicleNumber 
    ODOmeter
    
      spItemCode
              spitemName ,
              spitemCost
              spitemManhours,
              spitemEstStartDTM  
              spitemEstEndDTM  
            totalSpareCost
    totalLabourTime
    totalLabourCost
    TotalCost
    vehicleRecoveryTime

Comment: my request object in json

Comment: please give some idea about this